# What is the PSTricks equivalent for 'control' in Tikz?

Tags: pstricks

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
%==================
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1, font=\footnotesize, line join=round, line cap=round, >=stealth]
\draw[->] (-0.5,0) -- (4,0) node[below] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-2) -- (0,3) node[left] {$y$};
\draw($(0,0)$)node[below left]{$O$};

\draw[blue] (-95:0.8)+(0,-1)..controls +(85:8) and +(-100:5)..(2,1)
..controls +(-70:1) and +(-110:0.5)..(3,2)
..controls +(-80:1) and +(95:0.5)..(3.4,-0.8)node[right]{$y=f'(x)$};

\draw[dashed] (2,0)node[below]{$2$}|-(0,1)node[left]{$1$};
\draw[dashed] (3,0)node[below]{$3$}|-(0,2)node[left]{$2$};
\draw[dashed] (0,-1)node[left]{$-1$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

P/s: I need a official way which will be used in the future.

Comment: It is `\psbezier*[par]{arrows}(x0,y0)(x1,y1)(x2,y2)(x3,y3)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no *direct* way to translate such kind of coordinates, but it can be done on PostScript level with the `!` operator! However, it makes no sense to plot a derivation of a function with bezier curves. PSTricks uses cubic splines but can also use other types. For a derivation one should use the optional argument `Derive` from `pstricks-add` or plot the derivation of a polynomial stepwise:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture*}[showgrid](-1,-2)(4,3)
\psaxes[labels=none]{->}(0,0)(-1,-2)(4,3)
\psplot[algebraic]{-0.1}{2}{3*(x-0.1)*(x-1.2)*(x-1.75)}
\psplot[algebraic]{2}{3}{3*(x-2.4)^2+0.7}
\pscurve(3,1.8)(3.3,0)(3.4,-1)
\end{pspicture*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, the plot from `TikZ` uses the `curve` procedure from pdf which has
another behaviour than the one from PSTricks.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-1,-2)(4,3)
\psaxes[labels=none]{->}(0,0)(-1,-2)(4,3)
\makeatletter
\psbezier(!0.8 -95 PtoC 1 sub)%
         (!2 copy \tx@UserCoor 8 85 PtoC addCoors)%
         (!2 copy \tx@UserCoor 5 -100 PtoC addCoors)%
         (2,1)%
         (!2 copy \tx@UserCoor 1 -70 PtoC addCoors)%
         (!2 copy \tx@UserCoor 0.5 -110 PtoC addCoors)%
         (3,2)
         (!2 copy \tx@UserCoor 1 -80 PtoC addCoors)%
         (!2 copy \tx@UserCoor 0.5 95 PtoC addCoors)%
         (3.4,-0.8)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: _the plot from TikZ uses the curve procedure from pdf which has another behaviour than the one from PSTricks_. The reason is "PostScript language different with TikZ language", isn't it?

Comment: no, PDF is a subset of PostScript with some more new features. Only with PostScript we can do any additional calculations before using a function, PDF can't.

Comment: Since the command _control_ into " _some more new features_ " so PSTricks hasn't it ?

Comment: `TikZ` is a package and `PSTricks` is a package. The first creates by default PDF code, PSTricks creates by default PS code, which then can be converted into PDF.  `control` is a special `TikZ` keyword for the `\draw` macro. PSTricks has a special macro `\psbezier` which do not need the keyword because the second and third pair of coordinates are by default the control points for a Bezier curve.

Comment: Wow, so in your second code, you use the data as TikZ's code above for _\psbezier in PostScript level_, but the output is not like it. _Why_? :-(

Comment: It means _which then can be converted into PDF_ will make the output is not like it !

Comment: the Bezier curve definitions of PostScript and the one of PDF are not the same!

Answer (score 1):

These are Bezier curves and they are implemented in `pstricks` via `\psbezier`, see p. 20 of the manual:

[image]

So far, so good. However, to the best of my knowledge neither automatic parsing of coordinates nor the `+(x,y)` syntax is implemented in `pstricks`. That is, there is no straightforward translation of your code to `pstricks`. Just to show that when quickly estimating the coordinates by hand one obtains a similar plot.

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-2)(4,3)
\psline{->}(-0.5,0)(4,0) 
\psline{->}(0,-2)(0,3)
\psbezier[linecolor=blue](-0.05,0.2)(0.3,6.7)(-0.2,-4.7)(2,1)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, I had no passion to employ `\pscalculate` to compute the coordinates more precisely nor to add several explicit `\rput`s, but if you have that passion you will be able to convert your picture to `pstricks`.

Comment: It doesn't look like the picture of OP.

Comment: @minhthien_2016 Yes, the picture is from the manual.